# How to set the title for the Eureka Form Page, Not Section

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Sorry for the really simple question but I couldn't seem to find the answer to this in the documentation and I'm really new to both swift and Eureka.  I understand how to set the title for each section but I can't seem to find where I'm supposed to set the title for the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

The ***form*** is a table view embedded in an `UIViewController`.

The appearance of the enclosing ***page*** is up to you for example a navigation controller or a header view.

Comment: Is there a way to embed the Form into a storyboard or do we have to do this all programmatically?  Are there any good examples that have a form in conjunction with a nav controller or header?

Comment: Just drag an UIViewController into the storyboard canvas and set the class of the controller to `FormViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your View Controller in your storyboard.  Then go to Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller.  Then go back to your view controller and then assign your title to the self.title variable.